# SSL errors when I activate my custom theme

Tags: themes, migration, ssl

Hi guys I have a problem, Im trying to import a Wordpress project to my localhost. I did all the required steps like importing the sql databases and changing the config file and whatnot.

So I am now able to enter the Admin portion of the site.

But I get an SSL error or at least what I assume to be an SSL error whenever I try to access the site itself (can't establish secure connection) and the address bar turns from http:// to https://

When I change the theme to twentyseventeen I am able to enter the site.

With this I can conclude that the problem lies within my theme.

I rechecked my wp-config and my .htaccess files and none of them point to any https stuff either! At this point I am completely stumped

So my question is does anyone know what files within the theme affects the SSL stuff?

Comment: You should also change the Db values in the options table to reflect the new urls. Also on the site do you support the https or not?

Comment: use the network monitor to look if all requests use HTTPS, e.g. with firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Drupalizeme above. Use phpmyadmin and go to wp-options table. you should see a line for siteurl. make sure it does not say HTTPS. There will most likely be a second line for the wordpress site which you should also check. Those two settings are usually in the Settings > General tab in the admin .